# Run groovy and grails with TextMate

Tags: macos, grails, groovy, textmate

I installed the groovy and groovy grails bundle for TextMate and also installed groovy and grails on my Mac. But when I want to run a Groovy Application I get the following error message.

```
Couldn't find /Users/<username>/.gvm/groovy/current

If you have installed groovy, then you need to either update your PATH or set the TM_GROOVY shell variable (e.g. in Preferences / Advanced)

Locations searched:

/Users/<username>/Library/Application Support/Avian/Pristine Copy/Bundles/groovy.tmbundle/Support/bin
/Users/<username>/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Managed/Bundles/Bundle Support.tmbundle/Support/shared/bin/CocoaDialog.app/Contents/MacOS
/Users/<username>/Library/Application Support/Avian/Pristine Copy/Bundles/groovy.tmbundle/Support/bin
/Users/<username>/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Managed/Bundles/Bundle Support.tmbundle/Support/shared/bin/CocoaDialog.app/Contents/MacOS
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/Users/<username>/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Managed/Bundles/Bundle Support.tmbundle/Support/shared/bin
/Users/<username>/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Managed/Bundles/Bundle Support.tmbundle/Support/shared/bin
/Users/<username>/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Managed/Bundles/Bundle Support.tmbundle/Support/shared/bin
```

I  set the TM_GROOVY variable to my groovy path `/Users/<username>/.gvm/groovy/current` but it didn't work. I've the same problem with grails applications.

Does someone know what I'm making wrong?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried `/Users/<username>/.gvm/groovy/current/bin` ?

Comment: If your run `groovy --version` from command line then what did you get? Also interested the output of the `which groovy`.